Polars match element length in different columns
I have a data-frame with multiple columns containing list items.
I eventually want to explode the list columns into rows. This will only work if all lists have the same length (per row).
df.explode("a", "b")

For each row, to match the number of elements in the lists, I would like to insert dummy items into the lists.
def generate_dummy(c1, c2):
    return pl.lit([""] * (pl.col(c1).cast(pl.Int32) - pl.col(c2).cast(pl.Int32)), dtype=pl.List(pl.String))


# Original dataframe
df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [[1, 2], [3], [4, 5], [1]], "b": [[4, 5, 7], [6], [4, 5], [3, 2]]})

# Collect the list lengths in each column.
df = df.with_columns(alens=pl.col("a").list.len(), blens=pl.col("b").list.len())

### ERROR STEP ###
# Add dummy element [""] where the length is shorter.
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("alens") > pl.col("blens"))
    .then(pl.col("b").list.concat(generate_dummy("alens", "blens")))
    .otherwise(pl.col("a").list.concat(generate_dummy("blens", "alens")))
)

But I am stuck when counting #'s of dummy elements to be added.
The error I get,
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[304], line 3
      1 df.with_columns(
      2     pl.col("a").list.concat(
----> 3         pl.lit(
      4             [""] * (pl.col("alens").cast(pl.Int32) - pl.col("blens").cast(pl.Int32)), dtype=pl.List(pl.String)
      5         )
      6     )
      7 )

File ~/data/opt/mambaforge/envs/orbital_py395/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/functions/lit.py:130, in lit(value, dtype, allow_object)
    127     return lit(pl.Series("literal", [value], dtype=dtype))
    129 if dtype:
--> 130     return wrap_expr(plr.lit(value, allow_object)).cast(dtype)
    132 try:
    133     # numpy literals like np.float32(0) have item/dtype
    134     item = value.item()

TypeError: cannot create expression literal for value of type Expr: <Expr ['[(Series[literal]) * ([(col("a…'] at 0x15007DCF7370>

Hint: Pass `allow_object=True` to accept any value and create a literal of type Object.

I tried with kwargs allow_object=True and end up with the error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ComputeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[305], line 1
----> 1 df.with_columns(
      2     pl.col("a").list.concat(
      3         pl.lit(
      4             [""] * (pl.col("alens").cast(pl.Int32) - pl.col("blens").cast(pl.Int32)), dtype=pl.List(pl.String), allow_object=True
      5         )
      6     )
      7 )

File ~/data/opt/mambaforge/envs/orbital_py395/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/dataframe/frame.py:8310, in DataFrame.with_columns(self, *exprs, **named_exprs)
   8164 def with_columns(
   8165     self,
   8166     *exprs: IntoExpr | Iterable[IntoExpr],
   8167     **named_exprs: IntoExpr,
   8168 ) -> DataFrame:
   8169     """
   8170     Add columns to this DataFrame.
   8171 
   (...)
   8308     └─────┴──────┴─────────────┘
   8309     """
-> 8310     return self.lazy().with_columns(*exprs, **named_exprs).collect(_eager=True)

File ~/data/opt/mambaforge/envs/orbital_py395/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/lazyframe/frame.py:1816, in LazyFrame.collect(self, type_coercion, predicate_pushdown, projection_pushdown, simplify_expression, slice_pushdown, comm_subplan_elim, comm_subexpr_elim, no_optimization, streaming, background, _eager, **_kwargs)
   1813 # Only for testing purposes atm.
   1814 callback = _kwargs.get("post_opt_callback")
-> 1816 return wrap_df(ldf.collect(callback))

ComputeError: cannot cast 'Object' type

How can i match the element count (of list) in multiple columns of a dataframe.?

You can create a new list columns with the desired number of dummy elements per row (on the fly) and concatenate them to the list columns to explode.

The target length for each row is computed as the maximum list length across all list columns to explode. For this, pl.max_horizontal can be used.
pl.lit can be used in conjunction with
pl.Expr.repeat_by to create a list column of n dummy elements per row. Here, n can also be an expression.
Finally, we concatenate the list of dummy elements to the lists to explode using pl.Expr.list.concat.

Note. In the example below, I've used -1 as dummy value to avoid changing the dtype of column "a" to list[str].
target_length = pl.max_horizontal(pl.col("a", "b").list.len())

(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("a").list.concat(pl.lit(-1).repeat_by(target_length - pl.col("a").list.len())),
        pl.col("b").list.concat(pl.lit(-1).repeat_by(target_length - pl.col("b").list.len())),
    )
)

shape: (4, 2)
┌────────────┬───────────┐
│ a          ┆ b         │
│ ---        ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64]  ┆ list[i64] │
╞════════════╪═══════════╡
│ [1, 2, -1] ┆ [4, 5, 7] │
│ [3]        ┆ [6]       │
│ [4, 5]     ┆ [4, 5]    │
│ [1, -1]    ┆ [3, 2]    │
└────────────┴───────────┘

